# Trying to include rows with NULL values + invalid length parameter error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having kind of a combination of issues with a SQL query I'm currently working with. The data has to do with people who have completed a submission, and my most important column is `SubmitDate`. Each time I run this query, I'm looking back a rolling 7 days from the current date, so I'm seeing data for some of the same people from day to day but also picking up new data as I go along.

Date columns in the database I'm working with typically display their dates in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, but the specifications for this data pull require dates to be in `YYYYMMDD` format, so I added some code that performs that conversion.

My query looks something like this:

```
SELECT
    p.PersonID,
    p.PersonName,
    p.[several other demographic fields like address, state, phone],
    LEFT(p.PersonZipcode,5) as PersonZip,
    s.SubmissionID
    s.SubmissionType,
    CONVERT(varchar(8),CAST(s.SubmissionDate as date),112) as SubmitDate,
    s.SubmissionStatus
FROM 
    Person p 
JOIN 
    Submission s ON p.PersonID = s.PersonID
WHERE 
    s.SubmissionDate BETWEEN DATEADD(dd,-7,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

This all works just fine. The catch is that occasionally there are results that have a `NULL` `SubmitDate` because whoever entered the data into the system didn't include it for some reason. And obviously since a `NULL` date doesn't fall within my specified date range, those rows get omitted from my results. I still need to be able to include them though, so I amended my `WHERE` clause to be like

```
WHERE (s.SubmissionDate BETWEEN DATEADD(dd,-7,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
    OR s.SubmissionDate IS NULL)
```

The logic here seems sound enough, but now when I try to run the query, SSMS throws an error:

> Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

I do have that `LEFT` function I'm using for the zip code field, since some zips are stored in our DB as zip +4 and the specs for this report only want the first 5 digits for consistency. But I guess my primary question is why attempting to include `NULL` dates seems to have triggered an error related to a completely different field. What should I do to remedy this?

### **ADDITIONAL INFO:**

Okay, I was trying to keep my example query simple just for the purposes of this question, but I do have another complicated `SUBSTRING` function (two, actually). There's another field required for this report, the name of the person each of the submissions were completed for (submitted to). In the DB, this field is formatted like Last Name, First Name + Credential (e.g. "Smith, John CPA") in a single string. However, the report specifications require the first and last names to be in separate columns, without the credential. See the updated `SELECT` statement below. This code works fine, but could this be what's causing the error when I try to include the `NULL` dates?

```
SELECT
    p.PersonID,
    p.PersonName,
    p.[several other demographic fields like address, state, phone],
    LEFT(p.PersonZipcode,5) as PersonZip,
    s.SubmissionID
    s.SubmissionType,
    CONVERT(varchar(8),CAST(s.SubmissionDate as date),112) as SubmitDate,
    s.SubmissionStatus,
    LEFT(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(s.SubmittedTo, CHARINDEX(', ', s.SubmittedTo), LEN(s.SubmittedTo)), ', ', ''),CHARINDEX(' ',REPLACE(SUBSTRING(s.SubmittedTo, CHARINDEX(', ', s.SubmittedTo), LEN(s.SubmittedTo)), ', ', '')) - 1) as SubmittedToFName,
    LEFT(s.SubmittedTo, CHARINDEX(', ', s.SubmittedTo) - 1) as SubmittedToLName

FROM Person p JOIN Submission s ON p.PersonID = s.PersonID

WHERE s.SubmissionDate BETWEEN DATEADD(dd,-7,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

Comment: Most likely your rows with a null date column also have invalid (maybe null) other columns.

Comment: `why attempting to include NULL dates seems to have triggered an error related to a completely different field` - this will be because you're now including rows that have those other issues - you never noticed the issue because you were previously excluding them.

Comment: Though the only column that has a `LEFT` or `SUBSTRING` is `LEFT(p.PersonZipcode,5)`, and that won't produce the error. I suspect one of those columns is a computed column.

Comment: You may want to select just the zip field to see if that's really the error, SELECT LEFT(PersonZipcode,5) FROM Person

Comment: Okay, the zip code field may indeed be the problem - when we went in and checked some of the wonky results manually, there was at least one person with a `NULL` submission date who was also missing all their address info.

Comment: `LEFT(NULL,5)` doesn't return an error though, @EJF , it returnn `NULL`. And even if a string is shorter than the second parameter, it won't error. `LEFT('A',5)` returns `'A'`. There's another `LEFT` or `SUBSTRING` you're not telling us about.

Comment: @Larnu but if that row with the `NULL` zip code was previously being omitted because it also had a `NULL` submission date, the query would run fine—now that I'm trying to include `NULL` dates, the `NULL` zip is also included, but the `LEFT` function can't find the 5 digits because that field is blank. Hence the error. Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: *"but the LEFT function can't find the 5 digits because that field is blank"* @EJF you didn't read my comment, *"`LEFT(NULL,5)` **doesn't** return an error"*. Including rows where `PersonZipcode` have a value of `NULL`, won't cause `LEFT(PersonZipcode,5)` to error. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=29512e0daaf642731b63143d50bdea4d)

Comment: @Larnu check out the additional info I just added to the question

Comment: ... This is why a [mre] is always important @EJF . With respect, you've wasted a lot of people's time who were trying to help you here.

Comment: @Larnu I don't know that any of the 3 other people who offered brief responses feel like I've wasted their time. Can you at least tell me if this new info looks like it could be the source of the error?

Comment: Yes, those could easily cause an error, @EJF if you don't handle a string no containing the character.

Comment: @Larnu What if I know for a fact all the names in the `SubmittedTo` field are formatted exactly the same and all have the space and the comma the `LEFT` and `SUBSTRING` functions are dealing with? A string "not containing the character" shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: The fact you are getting the error suggests others, @EJF. Without an [mre] then there's little more I can say.

Answer (score 1):

You need to query the Submission table and check the SubmittedTo field for an empty string i.e. ‘’ If that yields no result then check the SubmittedTo field for a value that DOES NOT contain a comma followed buy a space i.e. ‘, ‘. You see that your left function gets the length parameter from CHARINDEX(', ', s.SubmittedTo) - 1) which can return -1 if s.Submitted to is an empty string or has no comma. Consider the following:

```
SELECT LEFT(NULL, 5) -- returns NULL notice no error 
SELECT LEFT('', 5) -- returns nothing notice no error

SELECT LEFT(NULL, -1) -- returns your error
SELECT LEFT('', -1) -- returns your error

SELECT CHARINDEX(', ',NULL) - 1 -- returns NULL
SELECT CHARINDEX(', ','') - 1 -- returns -1

SELECT LEFT(NULL, CHARINDEX(', ',NULL) - 1) -- returns NULL no error 
SELECT LEFT('', CHARINDEX(', ','') - 1) -- returns your error
SELECT LEFT('', CHARINDEX(', ','somevalue') - 1) -- returns your error
```

Not an exact answer to your question but I think this should help you find the problem.